# Delete Photo, only remove file but not record in database - upload multiple images in collection form type

Tags: jquery, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I really need your help.

I try to make:
Form Collection by ninsuo symfony-collection  which have field to upload file (image) by VichUploaderBundle.

I can add new collection element and put image to input - it works

When i try to check delete file in collection form, my file will be delete from server, but i have still record in database - only image_name and image_size dissapear.

Please help with this. I put some images to show how it works. Tell me what should I check in my code. I have Symfony4. I use ninsuo symfony-collection and VichUploaderBundle.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sySja.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5axU.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlWxo.png
```

Entity CAR:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="car", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $photos;
```

Entity PHOTO:

```
/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="photo", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     maxSize = "1M",
 *     maxSizeMessage = "Maksymalny rozmiar zdjęcia to 1 MB.",
 *     minWidth = 100,
 *     maxWidth = 3000,
 *     minHeight = 100,
 *     maxHeight = 3000
 * )
 */
private $imageFile;
```

FormType: CARTYPE

```
->add('photos', CollectionType::class, [
                'label'        => false,
                'entry_type'   => PhotoType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype'    => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-collection',
                ],
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false
                ],
            ])
```

FormType: PHOTOTYPE

```
->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'download_uri' => false,
                'download_label' => false
            ));
```

TwigTemplate: ADDCAR - fragment with script code

```
$('.form-collection').collection({
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        allow_duplicate: false,
        allow_up: false,
        allow_down: false,
        add: '<a href="#" title="Dodaj"><span class="fa fa-plus-square"></span></a>',
        remove: '<a href="#" title="Usuń"><span class="fa fa-minus-square"></span></a>',
        add_at_the_end: true
    });
```

Controller: ADDCAR

$form = $this->createForm(CarType::class, $car);

```
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /** @var Car $car */
            $car = $form->getData();
            $car->setUser($this->getUser());

            foreach($car->getPhotos() as $photo){
                $photo->setCar($car);
            }

            $entityManager->persist($car);
            $entityManager->flush();}}
```

Comment: What does the code for deleting look like, e.g. your controller action?

Comment: I add fragment to description problem, nothing special validation and save to database.

Comment: Now I found small solution. I need to add: orphanRemoval=true to photos field and I must click on remove element in collection, not checked remove photo from image file type. `code`/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="car", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $photos;